# Is it normal for a program to bring down my Desktop

Tags: 16.04

When running a program that is heavy on resources it sometimes stops everything else from running. Entering Alt-F2 to open a terminal and kill it has no effect and my only recourse is to power off an on my machine. Is this something I just have to tolerate with Ubuntu or do I have any other alternative ways of killing the program?

Comment: No, it's not normal, but there are some things that can be done to minimize/eliminate problems. Show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`.

Answer (score 1):

If your system suffers from an Out-of-memory condition, there is a low-level key combination that will kill the process that uses the most RAM. To do so, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>SysRq</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.

More of these "Magic SysRq Key" combinations can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key).

Comment: The only Magic SysRq key combo that seems to work for me is Alt+SysRq+b for a hard reboot. Entering any other combinations has no effect for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I have found is to use the Ctrl-Alt-F_ key sequence to open a separate terminal and kill the offending process. Although it usually takes a long while to respond to this key sequence.